# How to group data from temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by, temp-tables

I have created one temporary table in which corresponding to one `fileid` which is primary key, I am having 5 rows. I want to get the count as 5. What query do I have to write to get the count corresponding to each `fileid`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, count(*) from #tmpTable
Group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(Primary_Key_Field) as PrimaryFieldCount, Primary_Key
From TmpTbl
Group by Primary_Key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     GroupByField,
     COUNT(*)
FROM 
     #TableName
GROUP BY
    GroupByField
```